# Saving to User Defaults in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am currently trying to save an array to the user defaults.

Here is my code:

```
//where things will be stored
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var taskNames = [String]()
var taskPriorities = [Float]()

//this is the function that saves tasks
func saveTask() {
    println(taskNames)
    println(taskPriorities)
    defaults.setObject(taskNames, forKey: "taskName")
    defaults.setObject(taskPriorities, forKey: "taskPriorities")
    defaults.synchronize()
}

//this is the function that loads tasks
func loadTasks() {
    var taskNamesLoad = defaults.dataForKey("taskName")

    println(defaults.dataForKey("taskName"))
    println(taskNamesLoad)
}
```

When I call the function to load the data (after saving some data with the other function of course) the output to the Console is nil and there is no data saved in the user defaults. How can I fix this?

Comment: what values you are passing?

Comment: I am passing the taskNames and taskProperties arrays to the user defaults,. The values for those come from a UITextFeild and a UISlider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `arrayForKey` or `objectForKey` instead `dataForKey`. Because you store the `Array` object, not `NSData`.

Like below:

```
func loadTasks() {
    var taskNamesLoad = defaults.arrayForKey("taskName")

    println(defaults.arrayForKey("taskName"))
    println(taskNamesLoad)
}
```

Comment: defaults.stringArrayForKey("taskName") as [String]

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to save to user defaults you need to use plist safe objects.  So instead of using `Float` you need to use `NSNumber`.

Comment: is there any way to save an array of Strings to the user defaults?

Comment: @StewartHering I would have imagined what you have would work.  If not then try using `NSString`.